# Regular expression not capturing all the elements

Tags: python, regex

I have created a regular expression to match a string which would have a "K" preceeded by 10 characters before and proceeded by 10 characters after.
[Check Demo Here](http://regex101.com/r/pE6tQ6/1)

However, I'm not able to detect strings wherever a K is said to exist. I would like to have multiple combinations of a string whenever a K is present ?

Comment: Better include your regex in question body with related Python code rather than a regex101 link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `re.findall()` :

```
print re.findall('([\w\n]{10}?K[\w\n]{10})',s)
```

result:

```
['GGKKKTKICDKVSHEEDRISQ', 'ISEILFHLSTKDSVRTSALST', 'FDSHRDSWIRKLRLDLGYHHD', 'HLDVHCFHDNKIPLSIYTCTT', 'PEFVSLP\nCLKIMHFENVSYP', 'ELILFSTMYPKGNVLQLRSDT', 'YAPLLQCLRAKMYSTK\nNFQI', 'DFVNTGGRYQKKKVIEDILID', 'RDLVISSNTWKEFFLYSKSRP', 'MLPTLLESCPKLESLILVMSS']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code is working fine however , the regex is not picking all the strings with "K" . It misses a few of them.